# What's the meaning of "for the best"?

Tags: meaning, usage

> Open his curtains for him so he can see God's beautiful work. And
>   he'll know that even things like this happen **for the best**.

I found this line from the movie, 'as good as it gets', and I'm curious about this phrase **'for the best'**. I searched its meaning in the dictionary and it said 'well', but I don't think it means 'well' in this context.

Comment: Google search on "for the best".

Comment: I googled it and I found the result like this: good in spite of the way it seems; better than you think or than it appears to be.

Comment: Definitely 'for the best' was used as adv in the line I quoted, but it is used as adj in the dictionary.

Comment: "And he'll know that even things like this happen **to eventually lead to something good**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there a couple of things happening in the sentences cited. First whoever "he" is seems to have suffered some sort of misfortune. Second the writer is obviously very religious and has the opinion that everything is part of God's plan and that God always has a positive motivation. So in spite of the immediate misfortune, for the "he" things will ultimately be "better" in some overall sense.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that even though something might not seem 'good' to us (for us), we have faith in Gods plans and his plans are 'for the best' for us.

Comment: While this answer correctly *uses* the phrase, I'm not sure it *explains* it much.